# put input inside two labels. It just shows the menu but I want to make toggle which helps to hide it again

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, toggle

I am using label tags and put some input with radio types between them.

```
<label class="text-left text-uppercase mt-1 sidenav-text w-100" for="category" onclick="menuShow();"  >Category</label>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <label class="text-left text-uppercase mt-1 sidenav-text w-100" for="value" onclick="valueShow();"  >value</label>
```

for the input, I used the js onclick function to show the values but I want the toggle here. I am feeling difficult to make it toggle. It will be great if you please resolve my problem.

```
<script>
    var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    function menuShow(){
        demo.innerHTML = `
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Women<br>
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Men<br>
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Kid<br>
        <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Boy<br>    
        `;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: a label semantically is a label (as the name suggest) for an input. A label is not designed to label multiple inputs (for that you have a fieldset). nesting a label inside a label or multiple inputs within a label is semantically incorrect and not intended.

Comment: So, is there any way to add multiple inputs @tacoshy

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. Thanks to everyone

Here is the solution.

```js
function myCategory() {
  var myCategory = document.getElementById('myCategory');

  if (myCategory.style.display === 'none') {
    myCategory.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    myCategory.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function myEdition() {
  var myEdition = document.getElementById('myEdition');

  if (myEdition.style.display === 'none') {
    myEdition.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    myEdition.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-sidenav-custom w-100" onclick="myCategory();">Category</button>

<div id="myCategory">
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Women Kurti<br>
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Teen Girls<br>
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Kid Girls<br>
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Men Kameez Shalwar<br>
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Men Kurta<br>
</div>

<button class="btn-sidenav-custom w-100" onclick="myEdition();">Edition</button>

<div id="myEdition">
  <input type="radio" name="select" value="women"> Online Edition <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Those functions could be just one that accepts an element. They're just togglers, after all. Also, you should use event handlers, not inline JavaScript.